# Identify single bouts and correct

Tags: r

I have a binary vector (ST):

```
ST <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
)
```

A series of 0's and/or 1's is equal to a single bout. So the first seven 0's is one bout (equating to 7 minutes). The '1' following this is also a single bout (1 minute).

I want to identify only the 1-minute bouts and correct them in the following way and create a new vector `newST`:

if the length of the bout is 1 minute look at the value of `ST` and if `ST == 0` then `newST == 1`, else `newST == 0`
So `newST` would be:

```
newST <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
)
```

I have looked at using `rle` to identify bouts and then to integrate into an `if` statement but no luck so far. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27213799/identify-periods-of-high-counts-in-timeseries-data) post was of some help in this respect.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the full result based on your input data? Are there any special cases you can think of? If yes, try including it in the test set ST.

Comment: @Roman. I have edited newST. Essentially, single 1-minute bouts need to be modified according to the details. There are no special cases. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by this: `if the length of the bout is 1 minute look at the value of ST and if ST == 0 then newST == 1, else newST == 0`

Comment: @989 Sorry if not clear. So if the 1-minute bout is a '0' it needs to be modified to a '1'. If it is a '1' it needs to be modified to a '0'.

Comment: @PharmR, following that logic, why is element 9 not converted to a 1? Do you need an iterative solution that checks repeatedly after each replacement?

Comment: @docendo discimus - you're right my apologies, have modified.

Comment: Two great answers below that both work and have up voted both. For simplicity of code I have ticked answer by @docendo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the updated question you can use `rle` and `inverse.rle`:

```
r <- rle(as.logical(ST))                 # check run lengths
r$values[r$lengths == 1] <- !r$values[r$lengths == 1]   # replace 1 min bouts
newST2 <- as.integer(inverse.rle(r))     # convert back
```

I'm using logical values inbetween since they're easily inverted.

Check result:

```
all.equal(newST, newST2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `rollapply` in `zoo`.

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
one_min <- rollapply(ST, 2, function(x) x[1]!=x[2]) %>%
  rollapply(2, sum) == 2
newST <- ST
newST[c(FALSE, one_min, FALSE) & ST == 0] <- 1
newST[c(FALSE, one_min, FALSE) & ST == 1] <- 0
newST
# View(data.frame(ST, newST))
```

Since `one_min` is shorter than original, so `FALSE` needed to be added to the start and end. With my cursory look at test data (`ST <- sample(0:1, size = 100, replace = TRUE`), the results look correct.

Comment: @ amatsuo_net. Thanks for your answer. Almost there - how could I modify so that it accounts for the modification required of the single '1' also - these need to change to '0'.

Comment: Added that part.